# Is there a way to get unpublished details of a page/dynamic component using Coreservice?

Tags: 2011, core-service

We have a requirement to generate  unpublished details of a page/Dynamic component.

Is there a way to get unpublished details(time, who) of the item(page/ dynamic component) using Coreservice?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the coreservice `GetSystemWideList` to get the transaction and loop through.

```
PublishTransactionsFilterData publishTransactionFilter 
                             = new PublishTransactionsFilterData();
List<PublishTransactionData> publishTransactionsList 
                             = _Client.GetSystemWideList(publishTransactionFilter).ToList();
```

`PublishTransactionData` - `Items` property will have all the information you need . You could also apply `PublishTransactionState` filter on `PublishTransactionsFilterData`.

Hope this information helps.

Comment: This particular code snippet gives the whole publish/unpublish transactions record available in tridion. Is there a way to get publish/unpublish details for a single Item(Page/Dynamic component) using coreservice ?

I can see in the CM DB PublishStates table has an entry for a Item like state cahnged and 0 - 1 to indicate published or not ... ? Is that possible to get that information along with who did it .

Comment: 0 or 1 just information whether it is published or not. It does not provide details. Since you need unpublish details this is only way AFAIK. You could also check `GetListPublishInfo` for a specific item, but that wont give you whether if it is unpublished. It provides only publish info (user/date etc..)

Answer (score 1):

These details are stored in the Publishing Queue, there you will find information about Who, time, publication, status.

Comment: Sorry i missed it in my question. i wanted to get it using Coreservice..